# Trying to automate a web page and pause in debugger error

Tags: selenium, web, automation

When trying to automate a webpage using selenium in chrome for mac, when trying to inspect to get the link Id ir greys out the page with a “ pause in debugger “ on top thus not allowing me to automate! What could be the solution?

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Can you share the error screen shot, I'm confused by your wording.